# Brushless AC generator types and their winding

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic, electricity, electric-machine

It is possible to make odd number of poles in the three phase exciter winding of brushless AC generator?

Comment: No need to yell.  Use regular capializatio rules for the title and text.

Comment: @JRE Question mark comes to mind too.

Answer (score 3):

A magnetic field always has a north and a south pole. Hence, you can't have an odd number of poles in any winding.

Even if you hypothetically did manage to come up with a way to do it, the poles are distributed around on a circle. Let's say we make 7 poles - you could then have say N S N S N S N . However, since they are on a circle, the first and the last N would be the same, and would just appear as one big N. Hence, you still end up with en even number of poles.

You can have a odd number of pole-pairs, but that is a different thing.